# Tangent Space View Direction based factor value remap

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, 3d

I'm trying to setup a mask similar to what Fresnel produces. Unfortunately Fresnel gives pretty bad results at grazing angles so I ended up using this :

```
float mask = abs(-viewDirTangentSpace.x / viewDirTangentSpace.z)
```

[image]

This gives a nice results but I would like to have values that evolves linearly. Is there a way to remap the range so it behaves like this (Photoshop) ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this `float mask = abs(atan(-viewDirTangentSpace.x / viewDirTangentSpace.z) / (PI * 0.5));`